# The type of a mathematical function for plot

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

Which mathematical function could interpolate these data points?

First I thought about something like $$f(x)=a\log(x+b)+c$$, but the first part is nearly linear and looks more like a logistic function. Logistic functions however can't produce such kind of "long tail" which feels more "*logarithmic*".

I can also describe the process which produces such data. Consider we have a number of valves. Each valve when opened starts to emit "something" by the $~e^{-x}$ law. So we open one valve after another until we open all of them and then we wait for some time after the last valve is opened. The presented plot contains curves with the overall number of "something" emited by all open valves from time obtained in a series of different experiments. The first "linear" part refers to the situation when we continuously open the valves one after another (it takes first two X squares on the plot) and the last "*logarithmic*" part is obtained when all the valves are opened.

[image]

Comment: some sort of arctan perhaps? from the process description, it sounds as though these functions are expected to be bounded, which rules out logarithms

Comment: I tried to interpolate by arctan as well as 1/(1+e^-x) and other simple sigmoids. The problem as I see it is that the tail of sigmoids is much more "bounded" than in my case, I don't know how to express it mathematically right, but what I see in the plots is much better described as "when opening valves it's linear, then after last valve is closed the sum becomes logarithmic"

Regarding valve "functions" - they are bounded to zero in eternity, yes.